# How to display tables in grid view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to running a code that retrieve data from database and show into page

as a table  .  Code is

```
<div>
          <h3>{{search_results|length}} Search Results Found...</h3>
          <p class="lead small" style="background-color: yellow;">These below values were real when the crawling happened at the specific duration('crawled_at').Now these values may vary or may not.</p>

             {% for sr in search_results %}
              <div class="col-md-4 row-md-4" >
               <table  class="table table-bordered" id="grid">
                    <tr class="row-md-3"><td class="col-md-1" width="12%">Item : </td>
                         <td class="col-md-2"  width="12%"><a href='http://flipkart.com{{sr.url}}'>{{sr.name}}</a></td> 
                    </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-4">
                      <td class="col-md-1" width="12%"> Price : </td>   <td class="col-md-2" width="12%">{{sr.price}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-3"><td class="col-md-1" width="12%"> Crawled at : </td>
                         <td class="col-md-2"  width="12%"> {{sr.crawled_at.strftime('%Y,%b %d.')}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-4"><td class="col-md-3" width="12%"> Rating : </td>

                         <td>{% if sr.rating%}{{sr.rating}}{% else %}-NA-{% endif %}</td>
                    </tr> 

                    </table>    
                    </div>


           {% endfor %}
           <p class="lead small" style="background-color: yellow;">If you are not happy with available results. you may <a href="/recrawl?search={{keyword}}">recrawl</a> now or later.</p> 
      </div>
```

and this give output in tables on the bottom of first table like this

[image: output is]

but i want to display all table as grid view .

the right side space must fill by the tables which show down side .

Comment: `table#grid { float: left; }.. table#grid ~ p { clear:both; }` BTW: the id should be unique on elements, so find a way to fix that and then use a class like `table.grid...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire page is divided into 12 grids. So wrap your all tables inside a div with 12 grid size and inside for loop create tables of grid size 4. Bootstrap will automatically do the things for you then. Try like this,

```
<div id="gridwrapper" class="col-md-12"> // It will occupy the entire page
{% for sr in search_results %}
              <div class="col-md-4> // Each div will occupy one 3rd of page which will make 3 column layout
               <table  class="table table-bordered" id="grid">
                    <tr class="row-md-3"><td class="col-md-1" width="12%">Item : </td>
                         <td class="col-md-2"  width="12%"><a href='http://flipkart.com{{sr.url}}'>{{sr.name}}</a></td> 
                    </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-4">
                      <td class="col-md-1" width="12%"> Price : </td>   <td class="col-md-2" width="12%">{{sr.price}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-3"><td class="col-md-1" width="12%"> Crawled at : </td>
                         <td class="col-md-2"  width="12%"> {{sr.crawled_at.strftime('%Y,%b %d.')}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row-md-4"><td class="col-md-3" width="12%"> Rating : </td>

                         <td>{% if sr.rating%}{{sr.rating}}{% else %}-NA-{% endif %}</td>
                    </tr> 

                    </table>    
                    </div>


           {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can directly give col-md-4 in the table and remove the div inside for loop as well

Answer (score 0):

To display elements on your page as a grid view you can use one of existing jquery plugins which work as a charm and with nice animations. You can find one which suits your need [in this post](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-grid-plugin/) or just search for "jquery plugin grid".